# PIGPIO instance in an object: object has no attribute 'pi'

Tags: python, pigpio

How the heck do I create and use a pigpio instance inside an object?  I feel like this should work?

```
import pigpio

class MyClass(object):

    def __init(self, pin_wake=8):
        self.pi = pigpio.pi()
        self.pin_wake = pin_wake
        self.pi.set_mode(self.pin_wake, pigpio.OUTPUT)
        self.pi.write(self.pin_wake, 1)


    def wake(self):
        self.pi.write(self.pin_wake,0)
        time.sleep(.1)
        self.pi.write(self.pin_wake,1)
```

I'm executing:

```
from myclass import MyClass
bot = MyClass()
bot.wake()
```

and getting

```
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'pi'
```

What gives?

Comment: Clue: you have not declared a method to initialise the class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by properly declaring the constructor.

Comment: How it looks now? Can you please show it in your answer?